# Converting working code into a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, subdirectory

Hi guys I needed to create a method to display current directory, files, subdirectories and the files of those subdirectories given a file the user has to choose. I accomplished the task and the fallowing code is printing the appropriated output. It is printing from the f.getParentFile() down, that is what  want. Now I want to use recursion instead. I am trying to learn the concept of recursion. I know you need a base case and then your inductive step, but when I try to modify my code into recursive I get an infinite loop when it hits the first subdirectory. Any feedback will be appreciated.

**NON-Recursive Working code**

```
static void listFiles(File f)
{
    try
    {
        if (f.exists())
        {
            File dir = f.getParentFile();

            if (dir.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("Directory:  " + dir );

                File[] list = dir.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i].isDirectory())
                    {
                        System.out.println("\tSubdirectory:  " + list[i].getName() + "\tsize :" + (list[i].length()/1024) + "KB" );
                        File[] listFiles = list[i].getAbsoluteFile().listFiles();
                        for (int j = 0; j < listFiles.length; j++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("\t\tSubdirectory files:  " + listFiles[j].getName() + "\tsize :" + (listFiles[j].length()/1024) + "KB" );
                        }
                    }
                    else if (list[i].isFile())
                    {
                        System.out.println("\tFiles:  " + list[i].getName() + "\tsize :" + (list[i].length()/1024) + "KB" );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else throw new FileNotFoundException("File ******** does not exists");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException | FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Attempting Recursion**

```
static void listFiles(File f)
{
    try
    {
        if (f.exists())
        {
            File dir = f.getParentFile();

            if (dir.isDirectory())
            {
                System.out.println("Directory:  " + dir );

                File[] list = dir.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                {
                    if (list[i].isDirectory())
                    {
                        System.out.println("\tSubdirectory:  " + list[i].getName() + "\tsize :" + (list[i].length()/1024) + "KB" );
                        listFiles(list[i].getAbsoluteFile());
                    }
                    else if (list[i].isFile())
                    {
                        System.out.println("\tFiles:  " + list[i].getName() + "\tsize :" + (list[i].length()/1024) + "KB" );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else throw new FileNotFoundException("File ******** does not exists");
    }
    catch(NullPointerException | FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to learn recursion, start with something simpler, like factorials.

Answer (score 1):

It is really really simple :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    filesInFolder("./");
}

public static void filesInFolder(String filename) {
    File dir = new File(filename);        
    for (File child : dir.listFiles()) {
        System.out.println(child.getAbsolutePath());
        if (child.isDirectory()){
            filesInFolder(child.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
}
```